Best way to aggregate data while applying filters
In many RESTful services that I have built, I often find the need to return a resource with nested resources while applying filters. These are typically retrieved in JSON format.
I have created a simple database schema with the following tables: articles, categories, tags, article_categories, and article_tags. This schema is just an example, but similar scenarios arise in any schema with relationships. Additionally, articles might have other n:m and 1:n relationships that could also be queried or filtered, but for the sake of simplicity, these are not included.
How can I query with aggregations in mind (n:m and 1:n) while addressing the following issues:

Join duplication
Reducing roundtrips (a single query)
Handling cases where some nested resources might be null (e.g., using LEFT JOIN with JSON_ARRAYAGG sometimes results in [null] instead of [])
Ensuring that filters are applied only to the main resource (e.g., if I filter articles by category.id = 1, the query should return articles with all associated categories, not just category 1)
The client cannot upgrade MySQL 5.7

The following fiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/Wyb1q3pC) contains this database schema with dummy data.
Currently, I am retrieving all articles along with their associated categories and tags using the following query:
SELECT 
  articles.*,
  IF(COUNT(categories.id), JSON_ARRAYAGG(categories.id), JSON_ARRAY()) as categories,
  IF(COUNT(tags.id), JSON_ARRAYAGG(tags.id), JSON_ARRAY()) as tags
FROM 
  articles 
  LEFT JOIN article_categories ON article_categories.article_id = articles.id 
  LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = article_categories.category_id
  LEFT JOIN article_tags ON article_tags.article_id = articles.id 
  LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = article_tags.tag_id
GROUP BY articles.id

Filtering based on articles is straightforward, but I am encountering difficulties in writing the following queries (since I'm unsure if it's possible to use the HAVING clause on these aggregated values):

Retrieve all articles (and their respective categories and tags) that have at least one category where c.name LIKE '%Sports%'.
Retrieve all articles (and their respective categories and tags) that have at least one tag within a tag hierarchy starting with parentId = ? (e.g., if an article has tags [Sports/Basketball, Lifestyle/Health] and you filter by Sports, this article should appear since Sports/Basketball belongs to the Sports hierarchy).

